# Visual studio 2008 - Clearcase integration Checkout issue

Tags: .net, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I've integrated clearcase plugin to visual studio 2008. I'm facing problem with unreserved checkout option with plugin.

I modified,
TOOLS -> options -> Rational clearcase -> clearcase user options . I removed the check "Reserved" under "operations" tab. I click OK.

After this setting , I selected a file to checkout --> a popup asking for comments appeared , BUT , Reserved is "Checked" in that final window for checkout. What ever we do that check is not going off. Pleaase help . Context is Unreserve checkout option by default for all the files. I modified the setting in CCRC also to default unreserved checkout.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any recent issue in this plugin in the [Integration CC - Visual Studio page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=1090&context=SSSH27&dc=DA410&dc=DA450&dc=DA430&dc=DA440&dc=D600&dc=D700&dc=DB510&dc=DB520&dc=D800&dc=D900&dc=DA900&dc=DA800&dc=DB540&dc=DB400&dc=DB560&dc=DB530&dc=DA600&dc=DB550&dc=D100&dc=DA420&dc=DA460&dc=DB300&dc=DA470&dc=DA480&dc=DB100&dc=DA4A10&dc=DA4A20&dc=DA700&dc=DA4A30&dc=DA400&dc=DA100&dc=DA500&dc=D200&dc=DB700&dc=DB600&q1=.net+toc&uid=swg27010873&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8&lang=all).

[image]

<sup>Note: the picture above is just here for general illustration.

It is not meant to say that you should click on the "unreserved, nonmastered" option: this is unrelated to your issue</sup>

Can you check that the file is actually checked out in reserve mode after you click ok on the checkout dialog?

You can do this with a a DOS session, by going on the parent directory of the file, and typing:

```
cleartool ls
```

By the way, what exact version of ClearCase are you using?
Are you using a full ClearCase client or only the CCRC gui? (meaning a light client communicating with a CCRC server)

Comment: You are right when i see in the CCRC after checkout from Plugin, it is showing unreserved, even though the Reserved option of checkout is marked as checked. But it is giving bad sign..